# Integration Material-UI with third-party react components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

Is there any recomended way how to style third-party components such as [react-paginate](https://github.com/AdeleD/react-paginate)
with [Material-UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/v1-beta) primitives (bars, buttons)? 
Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to do this today is use [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/). These allow you to pass in any 3rd party component and style them to your needs. [Here](https://medium.com/@newswim/styling-third-party-components-with-styled-components-d82ac073d423) is any example of how to do this with antd. Would be similar for you, except using Material UI components.